# "Aw, snap!" (chromium bugs out)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, chromium, debugging

I didn't had this issue before but now (without any software or hardware change) "aw snap" screens tend to appear very frequently and it's very irritating!!!

I tends to happen (I think) more often when I watch a youtube video.

I have 16GB ram an FX 8350 a Nvidia GTX 650 Ti 2048GB and a dual monitor set at 1080p each monitor I run ubuntu 16.04lts and everything is up to date (including the proprietary drivers for Nvidia and AMD) my internet access is over ethernet (50 mbps VDSL PPPoE)

and as I said using the same rig and OS I didn't had a single "aw snap" instance for months! but lately I have like at least one a day and some days it's like 10 a day.... it's irritating...

how could I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

It's Google's fault: youtube or chromium, or maybe both. It happens to me too. Quite often. They are making some radical changes to Youtube, completely removing flash from it, and , at the same time, adding more features like webm standard, in-motion preview of clips, implementing some torrent-like local streaming for faster incremental loading, etc.

Try changing your browser for a while, or watching youtube clips in SMPlayer, Minitube, etc. Youtube will load slower, but the overall performance will be more stable.

Comment: Thanks for the tip something kinda irrelevant when you comment on youtube videos and you push "+" does it pop a list with relevant usernames? because it used to do that but now it doesnt

Comment: Sorry about that. It's less of an Ubuntu problem, it's more like a Youtube issue. Maybe you could try this forum: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/youtube. for better support.